# SolidJS Create Resource - Uncaught Error in Promise

Tags: solid-js

I'm new to SolidJS and I'm having a weird error with resources. Here is my code:

```
export const authUserResource = createResource(
    () => axios.get<AuthUser>('/expense-tracker/api/oauth/user').then((res) => res.data)
);

export const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data] = authUserResource;
    createEffect(() => console.log('HasChecked', data.loading, data.error, data()));
    return (
        // ...
    )
}
```

The intent of the API call is to retrieve data on the currently authenticated user, or to return a 401 if the user is not currently authenticated. My intent is to then redirect the user based on their authentication status.

Well, the API is called and it is returning a 401 because the user is not authenticated. All of this is expected. What is not behaving is the SolidJS resource.

If the API returns a 401, I would expect the SolidJS resource data to meet these conditions:

```
data.loading === false
data.error instanceof Error
data() === undefined
```

Instead, I am finding that it is still at these conditions, based on the console.log statement in the above code example:

```
data.loading === true
data.error === undefined
data() === undefined
```

I also get an "Uncaught Error in Promise" error message in the browser JS console.

I'm hoping to figure out what I am doing wrong here to make the resource correctly handle the error so that I can gracefully handle this in my application.

Comment: Does it help if you replace `axios.get<AuthUser>('/expense-tracker/api/oauth/user').then((res) => res.data)` with `axios.get<AuthUser>('/expense-tracker/api/oauth/user').then((res) => res.data).catch((err) => { throw err })`? I think otherwise `createResource` can't capture the exception.

Comment: You can read this  [discussion](https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/705) around the issue

Answer (score 0):

> I also get an "Uncaught Error in Promise" error message in the browser JS console.

I also had the same issue and this comment: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/705#discussioncomment-2968407 helped.

You access `data()` but it is not allowed when there is an error. So you have to guard the call to `data()` with `data.state === "ready"` or via the other means as described here: https://docs.solidjs.com/references/api-reference/basic-reactivity/createResource#version-140-and-later

> My intent is to then redirect the user based on their authentication status.

I would do this inside `authUserResource()`, handle the 401 there and only use the resource/signal result for injecting the API data into the view.